# Twig : separator in a "for" tag

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is there a syntax to separate some elements in a "for" tag please ?

For example I have a list of users, and I want to display their username with a "-" separator, so the expected result would be : `Mickael - Dave - Chris - ...`

I have found this solution :

```
{% for user in entity.users %}
    {{ user.name }}{% if not loop.last %} - {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this is not very elegant. The [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter does not seem appropriate in a loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, no, you can't use the [`join`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter for your use case without workarounds. This is because you need to pull `getName` out of the object property. `join` just link each element of the `Traversable` instance with the given `glue`.

There are however some workarounds if you need it.

### Add a __toString method

In your `User` entity, you can add a `__toString` method to get the name of the user by default.
You should however take care if no other object are using the current default `toString` as it may cause conflicts

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Entity;

class User
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your twig the `join` filter

```
{{ entity.users|join(' - ') }}
```

### Map the usernames in the controller

In your controller, right before sending parameters to the view, you can map all the usernames for them to fit in an array.
*Note: I assume `getUsers` is a [`PersistentCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html), if not, use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) instead*

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Controller/MyController#fooAction

$users = $entity->getUsers();
$usernames = $users->map(function(User $user) {
    return $user->getName();
});

return $this->render('AcmeFooBundle:My:foo.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'usernames' => $usernames
);
```

Then in your twig

```
{{ usernames|join(' - ') }}
```

### Create a TWIG filter

In your application, you can create a [Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html). In this example, I'll create a filter called `joinBy` which will act like `join` by specifying a method to join elements by.

#### Service declaration

Straight and easy, nothing too harsh but a standard declaration like in the docs

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
acme_foo.tools_extension:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\Twig\ToolsExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

#### Extension creation

<kbd>**@Acme\FooBundle\Twig\ToolsExtension**</kbd>

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension, Twig_Filter_Method;
use InvalidArgumentException, UnexpectedValueException;
use Traversable;

/**
 * Tools extension provides commons function
 */
class ToolsExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_foo_tools_extension';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'joinBy' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'joinBy')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Implode-like by specifying a value of a traversable object
     *
     * @param mixed  $data  Traversable data
     * @param string $value Value or method to call
     * @param string $join  Join string
     *
     * @return string Joined data
     */
    public function joinBy($data, $value, $join = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($data) && !($data instanceof Traversable)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                "Expected array or instance of Traversable for ToolsExtension::joinBy, got %s",
                gettype($data)
            ));
        }

        $formatted = array();

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $formatted[] = $this->getInput($row, $value);
        }

        return implode($formatted, $join);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the input of a given property
     *
     * @param  mixed  $row  An array or an object
     * @param  string $find Property to find
     * @return mixed  Property's value
     *
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException When no matching with $find where found
     */
    protected function getInput($row, $find)
    {
        if (is_array($row) && array_key_exists($find, $row)) {
            return $row[$find];
        }

        if (is_object($row)) {
            if (isset($row->$find)) {
                return $row->$find;
            }

            if (method_exists($row, $find)) {
                return $row->$find();
            }

            foreach (array('get%s', 'is%s') as $indic) {
                $method = sprintf($indic, $find);

                if (method_exists($row, $method)) {
                    return $row->$method();
                }
            }

            if (method_exists($row, $method)) {
                return $row->$method();
            }
        }

        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf(
            "Could not find any method to resolve \"%s\" for %s",
            $find,
            is_array($row)
                ? 'Array'
                : sprintf('Object(%s)', get_class($row))
        ));
    }
}
```

#### Usage

You can now use it in your twig by calling

```
{{ entity.users|joinBy('name', ' - ') }}
# or
{{ entity.users|joinBy('getName', ' - ') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `__toString()` method in the Entity Class, and it's done.

and use native Twig's [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter, as in `{{ entity.users|join(' - ') }}`.